# Avoiding the word 'that'

Tags: conjunctions

> 1) Mike sees Christina is looking at Alex
>
> 2) Mike sees **that** Christina is looking at Alex

I read some suggestion saying don't use 'that' frequently in writing and try to avoid it where ever possible. So I removed that in the 1st sentence but I'm not sure whether it's really correct in this context.

Comment: I would prefer "Mike sees Christina looking at Alex."

Comment: That suggestion is **only a style suggestion & the preference of one group of writers & English teachers**. I don't understand the point to it. For me, S1 & S2 have slightly different meanings & should be used in different contexts: they aren't interchangeable. Neither sentence has a larger context, so it's not possible to say anything more than that they're both grammatically correct & evoke a similar image. But why was the sentence used? That's the context required for judgment. Some native speakers may disagree, though.

Comment: @BillFranke If you don't mind me picking your brain, what difference in meaning do you see between S1 & S2?

Comment: @Soulz: Because S2 is more formal & distanced than is S1, & because I too prefer "Mike sees Christina looking at Alex", I see S1 focused on a person and S2 focused on an act. That's the difference for me.

Comment: @BillFranke Looked at the two sentence again after reading your comment, and I see what you mean. I guess context would make it clear what the writer wants to focus on. Thanks for replying. :)

Comment: In my idiolect, *that* is required.  I have no problem with other people removing it, but I would feel strange saying sentence one myself.

Answer (score 4):

Omitting *that* is acceptable in this context; a more detailed description of when *that* may be omitted is available at your later question, [When can I remove the word 'that' in a sentence?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/6835/when-can-i-remove-the-word-that-in-a-sentence).

As to the suggestion “don't use ‘that’ frequently in writing and try to avoid it wherever possible”—this is an overstated and under-nuanced version of what is actually very sound practical advice: be careful of how and when and how often you use this overworked word.

*That* has five distinct uses in English:

1. As a demonstrative pronoun: ***That**’s the man I saw!*
2. As a demonstrative adjective (determiner): *I saw **that** man!*
3. As a relative pronoun (relativizer): *He’s the man **that** I saw.*
4. As a subordinating conjunction (subordinator): *I told you **that** I saw him.*
5. As an adverb: *The man was about **that** tall.*

***That***’s a lot of uses; and they’re all very common, so it’s very easy to use *that* repeatedly without noticing. It's even possible to stack four *that*s in a row, in four different senses, without being grammatically ‘incorrect’:

> I told you that<sub>4</sub> that<sub>1</sub> that<sub>3</sub> that<sub>2</sub> man said was totally false.

***That***’s hard to parse; and even though you’re unlikely to produce anything **that** awkward (I had to work hard to produce **that**), you still want to be careful not to confuse the reader even momentarily by using too many *that*s. It’s bad practice to use any word in two different senses in the same short passage; and this is particularly dangerous with *that*, because one of its uses (4) is to distinguish major syntactic units.

So be careful with your *that*s. Repetition of *that* in the ***same*** sense is OK, because it can establish rhetorically useful parallels; but if you notice you’re using it in different senses, look for ways to paraphrase. Here are a few:

- You may omit many conjunctive<sub>4</sub> and relative<sub>3</sub>
  *that*s (see the link).
- You may always substitute *who* or *which* for relative<sub>3</sub>
  *that*.
- You may often replace a demonstrative pronoun<sub>1</sub> with a personal pronoun or with *what*.
- You may sometimes replace the demonstrative adjective<sub>2</sub> with *this*, or the adverb<sub>5</sub> with *this* or *so*.

And so forth. Don’t avoid using *that*—***that***’s just silly. But ***do*** avoid using *that* confusingly.

Comment: Just for fun, two other examples of awkward sentences with repeated words:

"Since only two of our tape drives were in working order, I was ordered to order more tape units in short order, in order to order the data several orders of magnitude faster"  --  "I was sort of out of sorts after sorting that sort of data". (D.E. Knuth)

Comment: @Bakuriu Or [this classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo)