# Dropping "is" / "are" with dropping "that"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-usage

The word **that** is often dropped in an informal speech.

But what about dropping **is** and **are**? Consider the following examples:

1. Examples that are not intended to be used in real documents: ...
2. Examples are not intended to be used in real documents: ...
3. Examples not intended to be used in real documents: ...

Are both 2 and 3 correct?

Comment: I don't think 2 is correct. 2 sounds like you are saying no examples are to be used. But the actual meaning is that certain examples are not to be used, which comes after the colon. It would be better if you provided a full sentence.

Comment: (2) has  a different sense, as @AIQ says, but (3) has the same meaning as (1).

Comment: @AIQ and Kate, I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fragments ('that...' in that phrase is a relative clause modifying 'Examples')
2. Clause (You have Subject and Predicate there)
3. Fragments ('not intended...' is participle phrase modifying the 'Example')

Note: Fragments aren't complete sentences as fragments are usually mere Subjects.

I hope this simple explanation is comprehensible.